# Как одному из дочерних элементу игнорировать `margin:0 auto` родителя

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Можно ли через изменением класса `left` добиться игнорирования margin:0 auto родителя?

```css
.wrapper
{
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
main
{
  margin:0 auto;
}
.left
{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <main>
    <div class="left">Этот блок должен быть слева.</div>
    <div>Этот блок должен быть по центру.</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Исходя из http://htmlbook.ru/html/main
Элемент `<main>` предназначен для основного содержимого документа. Содержимое должно быть уникальным и не включать типовые блоки вроде шапки сайта, подвала, навигации, боковой панели, формы поиска и т. п.

```css
.wrapper
{
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.left
{
  margin:0;
}
main
{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Этот блок должен быть слева.</div>
  <main>
    <div>Этот блок должен быть по центру.</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Это и правильно и работает на [сайте](https://aliya.ilya.pp.ua/c/BagsPurses.html), тут в примере оно не срабатывает, наверно из-за неограниченной ширины.
Но раз уж задал такой вопрос, хочется узнать, можно ли было это сделать из первого примера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю не колдовать с границей дочернего блока, а поменять иерархию блоков:

1. Снаружи – структурные элементы (`<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>`...).
2. В них – контейнеры (на всю ширину, по центру или какие ещё нужны).
3. В контейнерах – полезное содержание.

И пусть в центральной колонке будет только то, что должно быть в центральной колонке:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <h1>Шапка</h1>
     <p>Текст шапки по центру.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <p>Текст шапки на всю ширину.</p>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <h1>Содержимое</h1>
     <p>Текст по центру.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <p>Текст на всю ширину.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Нельзя, по крайней мере из документации, так использовать `<main>`.
До `<header>` и `<footer>` нужен `<div class="wrapper">`, или любого другого класса, для задания общей ширины и центрирования сайта. и в него уже должны быть вложены `<header>` и `<footer>`, а между ними навигация, заголовки, боковые меню и `<main>` который должен содержать только уникальную информацию. (для ru.stackoverfow.com Заглавие темы, вопрос, ответы, комментарии и ничего больше)

Comment: @IlyaIndigo Дайте, пожалуйста, цитату из документации со ссылкой на источник. По-моему, вы говорите об одном из возможных решений, которое для вашей задачи не слишком подходит.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/main Элемент предназначен для основного содержимого документа. Содержимое должно быть уникальным и не включать типовые блоки вроде шапки сайта, подвала, навигации, боковой панели, формы поиска и т. п.

Comment: А где здесь про обязательный контейнер снаружи от `<main>` и про запрет на использование контейнеров внутри `<main>`?

Comment: Нет. то уже мои нужды. Обязательным является то, что `<main>` не должна всебя включать ничего, кроме уникальной информации, а следовательно враппер должен быть перед ним, и его не должно быть внутри.

Comment: В цитате говорится, что `<main>` не должен включать `<header>`, `<footer>` и прочее. Не вижу запрета на то, чтобы заворачивать содержимое в дополнительные блоки и растягивать их на всю ширину или выравнивать по центру.